# Karaf does not start

Tags: apache-karaf, karaf

I am using Karaf 4.1.1 on Windows. When i start the karaf container double clicking karaf.bat, i see only the below lines in the log. Nothing is seen in the shell. Any help appreciated. Thanks

```
org.apache.karaf.main.lock.SimpleFileLock lock
INFO: Trying to lock <userlocation>target\assembly\lock
org.apache.karaf.main.lock.SimpleFileLock lock
INFO: Lock acquired
org.apache.karaf.main.Main$KarafLockCallback lockAquired
INFO: Lock acquired. Setting startlevel to 100
```

Answer (score 0):

check the configuration section. look for the logging. Karaf use this to define the logging and the logging to the consule. it is log4J by default

http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/#_configuration_files

you can see that athe consule appender is not define by default

```
# CONSOLE appender not used by default
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} | %-5.5p | %-16.16t | %-32.32c{1} | %X{bundle.id} - %X{bundle.name} - %X{bundle.version} | %m%n
```

to enable it you need to add the stdout to the  root logger

something like this:

```
# Root logger
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, out,stdout osgi:*
```

PS* if still doesn't work I would download a new version, it is easily get curropted on windows.